# Angular custom library: can we export more than one service?

Tags: angular

After creating a custom library test-lib, I can export TestLibService, TestLibModule and TestLibComponent through public-api.ts. I can use TestLibService from the custom library within an Angular App.

app.module.ts looks like that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestLibModule, TestLibService } from 'test-lib';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TestLibModule
  ],
  providers: [ HttpRequestService, TestLibService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It works fine.

If I add a new service into test-lib called AnotherTestLibService and add a new corresponding line into public-api.ts, I can build without error my Angular app (ng build), but I end up with this error when I want to run my Angular App (ng serve):

```
Error: export 'AnotherTestLibService' (imported as 'AnotherTestLibService') was not found in 'test-lib' (possible exports: TestLibComponent, TestLibModule, TestLibService)
```

Here is the public-api.ts

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of test-lib
 */

export * from './lib/test-lib.service';
export * from './lib/another-test-lib.service';
export * from './lib/test-lib.component';
export * from './lib/test-lib.module';
```

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestLibModule, TestLibService, AnotherTestLibService } from 'test-lib';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TestLibModule
  ],
  providers: [ HttpRequestService, TestLibService, AnotherTestLibService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What is wrong or missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you build again your library?

Comment: yes. Rebuilt, repackaged and reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I needed to do a **ng cache clean** because it seems that the cache stored the exported classes and if you change the service name and add a new one, there is a risk that Angular cli has not updated the cache.